# create and update field to other model backpack laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to create a dashboard to display a specific table and create/update the lines for this table via backpack laravel.

For example I want to display a table of area and this table has a relationship with the cities table.

my problem is when I want to add a specific area and the city associated with it is not added !!.

That I do not want to go to add the city then back to add the area.

This is a very small example of what I'm really dealing with ,
since I want to add a line in a table and this line contains relationships with other tables I want to create on the same page.

I searched and did not find a direct answer. Does it make sense that a new view should be created? 
Does the Backpack Laravel not provide a solution to this problem?

If the answer is no and this is what I saw, what is the best solution to this problem ?

**Image to summarizes the problem as I want to create the city on the same page as creating the area**

[image]

Comment: You have to show your code too and explain  what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re looking for is what we call the [InlineCreate Operation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-inline-create) in Backpack. It adds a “+ Add” button next to the relationship field, so that the admin can add a related item right there, in a modal.

Check out [its docs here](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-inline-create).